# How can I differ classes with virtual methods

Tags: c++, virtual-functions

I have base class and 2 inheritors.

```
class A{
    virtual double calc();
    /.../
}

class B: public class A{
    virtual double calc(){} 
    /..../  
}

class C: public class A{
    virtual double calc(){} 
    /..../  
}
```

And there is a function:

```
void func(A *input1, A* input2){
....
}
```

which is invoked in this way:

```
C ptrC;
B ptrB;
func(&ptrB, &ptrC);
```

So, how can I understand inside func, if arguments input1, input2 are of the same or different type?

Comment: Adding a "type" variable to your class would be one possibility, using typeid/typeof another one

Comment: I can spot an error here, not defining encapsulation level for calc, in a class it will be by default private, only in a struct this is by default public, so B and C will not be able to access calc, so in B and C calc is not inherited from the vtable.

Comment: You have to ask yourself *why* you would want to know that, everybody else here wonder it too. Using type-information to distinguish between objects is usually a sign of bad design, and with virtual functions do you even need to care?

Comment: Yes, I know, that this is a bad design, but it's just some kind of training example.

Comment: Then this "example" is also bad...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use dynamic_cast OR typeinfo to get information:-

```
B* b = dynamic_cast<B*>(input)
if ( b == NULL )
   //Object of type C.
```

OR

```
if (typeid(A) == typeid(input) )
   //Object is of type A.
```

But it's preferable that you should avoid these things completely. That's the whole essence of virtual functions.

Comment: Thank you!
It's just an example. I'll never use this to solve real problems.

Answer (score 0):

You can do `typeid(*input1) == typeid(*input2)`. But consider carefully whether this is really what you want, or if you are actually looking for a solution to the [Binary Method Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_dispatch).

Answer (score 0):

```
if(typeid(*input1)==typeid(*input2)){
    //do something
}
```

You must have rtti enabled